"invalidfont" error with LuaLaTex and pst-barcode using basic TexLive install
I am trying to make a minimal TexLive install for a docker container to minimize cloud costs. My web app creates product package labels with a UPC code. In my docker container, I get an "invalidfont" error generating the UPC code. I am convinced this is an issue arising from a missing package dependency because it compiles perfectly using my local full LaTex installation. Any ideas on what I could be missing? Or is there a way to find out exactly what packages were used to successfully compile a TEX file so I can only install those in my container?
This is my minimal installation script in my Dockerfile. You can see that in addition to the minimal installation ("scheme-basic") I am using tlmgr to install fontspec, pst-barcode, pstricks, xcolor, xkeyval, pgf, luapstricks, pst-tools, marginnote, and phonetic:
# Use the most up-to-date version of Ubuntu LTS
FROM ubuntu:22.04

# Install necessary system utilities
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
        wget \
        perl \
        python3 python3-pip python3-dev python3-venv \
        fontconfig \
        ghostscript && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Download and install TeX Live
RUN wget https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz && \
    tar -xzf install-tl-unx.tar.gz && \
    cd install-tl-* && \
    echo "selected_scheme scheme-basic" > texlive.profile && \
    ./install-tl -profile texlive.profile && \
    cd .. && \
    rm -rf install-tl* install-tl-unx.tar.gz

# Set the PATH to include the TeX Live binaries
ENV PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/aarch64-linux:${PATH}"

# Install missing LaTex packages
RUN tlmgr update --self --all
RUN tlmgr install fontspec pst-barcode pstricks xcolor xkeyval pgf luapstricks pst-tools marginnote phonetic

# Set the working directory to root's home directory
WORKDIR /root

# Copy the fonts and images directories and TEX file
COPY fonts /root/fonts
COPY img /root/img
COPY label.tex /root/label.tex

# Move and cache fonts
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/fonts/custom && \
    cp /root/fonts/*.otf /usr/share/fonts/custom/ && \
    fc-cache -fv
RUN ls -la /usr/share/fonts/custom
RUN fc-list

# Expose the port the app runs on
ENV PORT 8080
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 8080

# Use the virtual environment's Python as the default
ENV PATH="/root/venv/bin:$PATH"

# Define the command to run the app
CMD ["lualatex", "label.tex"]

This is my label.tex file. You will see that I have three instances of psbarcode but only the first one wrapped in tikzpicture throws the error:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\usepackage{phonetic}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\geometry{paperwidth=4in, paperheight=2in, top=-0.5in, bottom=0.125in, left=0.125in, right=0.125in}

\renewcommand{\textsuperscript}[1]{\raisebox{0.8ex}{\scalebox{0.66}{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\fontsize{7pt}{8pt}\selectfont
\textbf{Company{\sffamily\textregistered} Product\\
Designed by Company\\
Assembled in USA\\
Model MP1
}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
\node[xshift=-1.5in,yshift=-0.45in] at (current page.north east) {\psbarcode{196852002825}{includetext width=1.3 height=0.35 textsize=9 textyoffset=-2 textxoffset=-6}{upca}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\vspace{0.075in}

\textbf{(A) Serial No. A12345678\\
}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0.35in)
\psbarcode{A12345678}{width=0.31 height=0.31}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}

\vspace{0.075in}

\textbf{(B) Serial No. B12345678\\
}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0.35in)
\psbarcode{B12345678}{width=0.31 height=0.31}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}

\vfill
\mbox{}\hfill \textbf{\textcopyright 2024 Company All rights reserved.}


\end{document}

This is my error:

[1 ! luapstricks: "invalidfont" error occured while executing PS code from "./labe l-docker.tex:29".  ...not:N \tex_shipout:D
\box_use:N \l_shipout_box
_shipout_drop_firstpage...
l.60 \end{document}
?  ! Emergency stop.  ...not:N \tex_shipout:D \box_use:N \l_shipout_box
_shipout_drop_firstpage...
l.60 \end{document}.
5544 words of node memory still in use:    80 hlist, 14 vlist, 1  rule, 14 disc, 10 local_par, 1 dir, 182 glue, 41.
kern,  43 penalty, 271 glyph, 90 attribute, 57 glue_spec, 90.
attribute_list, 1 temp,  2 if_stack, 4 write, 2 save_pos, 18 late_lua,
34 pdf_literal, 14 pdf_colorstack  nodes    avail lists: 2:3,5:2,10:4
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!


the log file run locally will show the full path to all packages used and all fonts loaded, or for more information use --recorder option and look at the .fls file.

have you installed these fonts </usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans10-bold.otf></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman7-bold.otf></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre/texgyreheros-regular.otf>

you could add tex-gyre and lm  packages to  to your tlmgr install line

@DavidCarlisle Thanks for the tip! Here is an excerpt of the FLS file.

@DavidCarlisle How would I parse this? Would I install all the .sty packages and assume any .tex are associated with the .sty package? In that case, I would have 28 packages that are in the FLS file.
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
INPUT /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex

well probably you jjust need the fonts as I mentioned above so install tex-gyre and lm, but the fls shows you which files are used, and tlmgr info xkeyval.sty etc will tell you what tlmgr package contains each file used so make sure you install each of those.
